# gtk-warning due to theme tweaking harmful to my stability or not?

Tags: unity, themes, ubuntu-tweak

I installed some theme, and enabled them via ubuntu-tweak.
when i run `nautilus --check` i get this error. Is this error harmful to ubuntu/unity/compiz's stability???.

```
(nautilus:6598): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: unity.css:21:19: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(nautilus:6598): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: unity.css:21:21: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(nautilus:6598): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: unity.css:21:25: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(nautilus:6598): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: unity.css:38:26: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(nautilus:6598): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: unity.css:39:27: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(nautilus:6598): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: unity.css:40:17: 'sahde' is not a valid color name

(nautilus:6598): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: nautilus.css:119:21: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, these warnings are **not at all** harmful to the stability of Ubuntu, Unity or Compiz. In fact most of the warnings won't affect *anything*: all the "deprecated" warnings are saying is that the standards recommend that units be used in the CSS files; the only warning that may affect looks is number 6, at line 40 in `unity.css`, about `'sahde'` being an invalid color.

Comment: Could you please improve your answer on how to fix `is not a valid color name`; `is not a valid image` and `is not a number` threads? As you say these could be harmful.