# What tool to use for testing GTK 3 Themes?

Tags: gtk3

Hello I am looking for a tool to check if every aspect of a gtk-3 part of a theme is fine.

Something like TheWidgetFactory, but for GTK3.

Comment: If you run gtk3 applications from a terminal, you may get some information. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/422254/why-are-there-so-many-console-messages-from-gtk-applications/422400#422400. Then there's also blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2014/05/15/introducing-gtkinspector/ but I think to get it working on Ubuntu you'll have to install `dev` gtk3 packages.