# Nautilus gives Gtk Warning when started

Tags: gnome, nautilus, dropbox

When I run **nautilus** this **warning** is generated. I installed **dropbox** from then its started, **But** then I

- uninstalled dropbox
- reinstalled nautilus
- reinstalled gnome-session

From my terminal:

```
~ nautilus

 (nautilus:27481): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

EDIT: I tried to **reinstall dropbox** and then **huge number of gvfs warning** came:

```
(nautilus:1510): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/sagarkar10/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
```

Then I **uninstalled dropbox and reinstalled nautilus** and the errors modified to::

```
(nautilus:2493): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:2493): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:2493): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(nautilus:2493): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:2493): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

Please Help me understand this error and get it solved. I am using **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**

**Note**: The errors in different stages are different, when i searched about those, not others facing the same.

Comment: If your program appears to be running normally, you can probably ignore any terminal messages. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/422254/why-are-there-so-many-console-messages-from-gtk-applications

Comment: It is annoying to see these again n again!

Comment: I get the same messages when I run `nautilus`. When I open it via Unity Launcher ("Files"), it quietly closes the window after several minutes. I doubt such errors should be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and had the exact same problem today here's how I solved it, first uninstall nautilus using :

`sudo apt-get remove nautilus`

and go ahead and reboot your PC

`sudo reboot`

reinstall nautilus using :

`sudo apt-get install nautilus`

My nautilus was broken so bad due to gnome3 install/update that it didn't work properly even after last step and there were some issues while minimizing and maximizing Terminal, so I uninstalled nautilus once again and installed this nautilus alternative named Nemo, now everything works just fine and nemo is way cooler than nautilus. Here's how to install Nemo :

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller`