# How do I get rid of the GTK warnings generated by evince?

Tags: themes, gtk3, evince, css

I use (L)ubuntu Zesty. If I call `evince myfile.pdf`, I get some warnings before the app comes up:

```
(evince:11529): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:23:18: not a number
(evince:11529): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:23:18: Expected a string.
(evince:11529): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:815:10: not a number
(evince:11529): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:815:24: Using Pango syntax for the font: style property is deprecated; please use CSS syntax
(evince:11529): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1953:14: not a number
(evince:11529): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1953:14: Expected a string.
(evince:11529): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: nautilus.css:50:71: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.
(evince:11529): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: nautilus.css:51:71: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.
(evince:11529): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-lubuntu.css:252:14: not a number
(evince:11529): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-lubuntu.css:252:14: Expected a string.
(evince:11529): Gtk-WARNING **: Allocating size to EvSidebar 0x55d3ce38f6a0 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
```

So, with the last error I'm guessing its hopeless since I'm not going to start fiddling with the app's code. But can I tweak the CSS files mentioned so as to avoid the warnings? If so, how? I don't quite understand these warnings.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/422254/why-are-there-so-many-console-messages-from-gtk-applications/422400#422400

Comment: @DKBose: I know these aren't really errors.