# GTK warning on using gedit command

Tags: command-line, gtk, gedit

I use Ubuntu 17.04. Every time I use gedit command in terminal I get a warning.

```
$ gedit sample.cpp
(gedit:6496): Gtk-WARNING **: Allocating size to GtkPaned 0x55bb7be10780 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
```

What is the cause of these warnings? Does it affect the system in any way? Is there any way to resolve them or should I just ignore them?

Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 reached EOL on 13-Jan-2018, was not (& won't be) patched for Meltdown, Spectre etc so I'd suggest release-upgrading to a supported release of Ubuntu (ie. 17.10). It's also now *off-topic* on this site.  As to your question, I'd just ignore them as warnings are mostly for development (debugging etc) use.

Comment: @ guiverc  Got it. So  these warnings do not shoot up in 17.10 or 16.04 LTS or 14.04 LTS?

Comment: :)  there is a chance that you won't see the messages in all three (the EOL has nothing to do with message). I read the message as a coder putting out a message to blame someone else should it fail....  (failure would require a hugely invalid value probably though [to cause overflow])

Comment: It's just a warning, not an error, so it can usually safely be ignored. I recommend you to use `xdg-open` to open files in their default application though, which should launch Gedit for all text files. It also runs in background and immediately releases your terminal again.

Comment: @ guiverc Wasn't intending to blame. Was just asking. In fact, since the warnings do not mean anything significant, I can afford to wait till April for 18.04 LTS.

Comment: You can look at my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/422400) as well as the others in the same Q&A.

Comment: It's a bug in `gedit` you can ignore. A python developer was reported this bug on January 18 and fixed it January 19. If only gedit developers moved as quick: https://github.com/Cimbali/pympress/issues/53